# Why does my Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() method return updated state after I reload and not when the useEffect's dependency runs (or login/logout)?

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm creating a ProtectedRoute component in React that will take a user state variable as prop.
This user is from my checkUser() func using amplify's Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().

```
function App() { 
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const { Auth, Hub } = useContext(AmplifyContext)

  async function checkUser() {
    try {
        const loggedInUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        setUser(loggedInUser);
        console.log(loggedInUser);
        // get null first time?

    } catch(e) {
        setUser(null);
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
  checkUser();
}, [Auth])

  return (
    
        <Router>
          <Suspense fallback={<p>...loading...</p>}>
            <Switch>

              <IsUserLoggedIn user={user} loggedInPath={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} path={ROUTES.LOGIN}>
                <Route path={ROUTES.LOGIN} component={Login} />
              </IsUserLoggedIn>

              <IsUserLoggedIn user={user} loggedInPath={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP}>
                <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} component={SignUp} />
              </IsUserLoggedIn>

              <ProtectedRoute user={user} path={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} exact>
                <Route path={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} exact component={Dashboard} />
              </ProtectedRoute>

              <Route path={ROUTES.RESET_PW} component={ResetPw} />
              <Route component={NoPage} />
              
            </Switch>
          </Suspense>
        </Router>
    
  );
}

// Protected Route Component
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import * as ROUTES from '../constants/routes';

export default function ProtectedRoute({user, children, ...restProps}) {
    console.log(user);
    return (
        <Route
            {...restProps}
            render={({location}) => {
                if(user) {
                    return children;
                }
                if(!user) {
                    return (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: ROUTES.LOGIN,
                                state: { from: location }
                                }}
            />
                    )
                }
                return null;
            }}
        />
    )
}


// login component

import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import AmplifyContext from "../context/amplify";
import * as ROUTES from '../constants/routes';

export default function Login() {

    const { Auth, Hub } = useContext(AmplifyContext);
    const history = useHistory();

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const invalid = !username || !password;

    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            // amplify Auth login
            await Auth.signIn(username, password);
            history.push(ROUTES.DASHBOARD);
            console.log('logged in');
        } catch(e) {
            setError(e.message);
            setPassword('');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="auth-container">
            <h2 className="auth-title">Log In</h2>
            <div className="login-form-container">
                <form className="form login-form" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                    <input autoFocus type="text" placeholder="username" aria-label="username" value={username} onChange={({target}) => setUsername(target.value)} />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password" aria-label="password" value={password} onChange={({target}) => setPassword(target.value)} />
                    {error && (<p style={{color: 'red'}}>{error}</p>)}
                    <div className="form-action-container">
                        <div className="button-container">
                            <button disabled={invalid} className="form-button" type='submit'>Log In</button>
                            <p>Need an Account? <span><Link to={ROUTES.SIGN_UP}>Sign Up</Link></span></p>
                        </div>
                        <p>Forget your password? <span><Link to={ROUTES.RESET_PW}>Reset</Link></span></p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The current problem is that the useEffect (or maybe the Auth method?) isn't updating the state and so the first time I click "login" in my login component, it returns 'null' from my protectedRoute component's as well as the main App component's `console.log(user)`, returning null. Only after I refresh, does it change and let me get the user log as well as directed into the protectedRoute.

This is also true for my logOut scenario.

```
export default function Dashboard() {

    const { Auth, Hub } = useContext(AmplifyContext);

    const history = useHistory();

    const handleLogOut = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // amplify call to sign out
        await Auth.signOut();

        history.push(ROUTES.LOGIN);
    }

    return (
        <div className="dashboard-container">
            <h1>Welcome </h1>
            <button onClick={handleLogOut}>log out</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I don't get logged out, nor do I get redirected unless I reload the page.
Why aren't the Auth.signOut() and the Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() methods run like I want it to?

Comment: I read through the amplify custom auth flow in the guides (https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/authentication/custom-auth-flow/q/platform/js#implementation-of-a-custom-authentication-flow), but I was wondering if it was possible to do it differently? (passing a user state data to my route helpers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

made her work a bit better after putting all auth related state into context provider and wrapping it around all {children} components and then using Hub to listen for changes to log out. (I had to stop using my route helper functions, so that's kind of a bummer. But it works at the moment. I will keep it as the solution). I had to use the amplify guideline for custom auth, so still not so satisfied...

Each related state variables that needs to be used in each component is using it from context (left it out for length).

```
// storing all state related to Authorization

import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import AmplifyContext from "./amplify";

const AuthContext = createContext();

function AuthContextProvider({ children }) {
    const [formType, setFormType] = useState("signUp");
    const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("");
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [authCode, setAuthCode] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const { Auth } = useContext(AmplifyContext);

    let invalid;

    const checkUser = async () => {
        try {
            const loggedInUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
            setUser(loggedInUser);
            console.log(user);
            if (user) {
                setFormType("dashboard");
            } else {
                setUser(null);
                setFormType("login");
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    };

    const handleSignUp = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            // amp auth signup. attribute must match (ie: if email is needed, state var needs to be called email (not other name))
            await Auth.signUp({ username, password, attributes: { email } });
            console.log("signed up");
            setFullName("");
            setUsername("");
            setEmail("");
            setPassword("");
            setFormType("confirmSignUp");
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
            setError(e.message);
        }
    };

    const handleConfirmAuthCode = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            // amp auth confirm sign up
            await Auth.confirmSignUp(username, authCode);

            setFormType("login");
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
            setError(e.message);
        }
    };

    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            // amplify Auth login
            await Auth.signIn(username, password);
            setUsername("");
            setPassword("");
            console.log("logged in");
            setFormType("dashboard");
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e.message);
            setPassword("");
        }
    };

    const handleLogOut = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // amplify call to sign out
        await Auth.signOut();
        //set some loading or redirect?
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                error,
                setError,
                handleSignUp,
                checkUser,
                handleConfirmAuthCode,
                handleLogin,
                handleLogOut,
                fullName,
                setFullName,
                username,
                setUsername,
                email,
                setEmail,
                password,
                setPassword,
                formType,
                setFormType,
                authCode,
                setAuthCode,
                invalid,
                user,
                setUser,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { AuthContextProvider, AuthContext };

// top
ReactDOM.render(
    <AmplifyContext.Provider value={{ Auth, Hub }}>
        <AuthContextProvider>
            <App />
        </AuthContextProvider>
    </AmplifyContext.Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);

// inside the App component (not yet finished)
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";

import AmplifyContext from "./context/amplify";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/AuthContext";
import ConfirmSignUp from "./pages/confirmSignUp";
import Login from "./pages/login";
import SignUp from "./pages/sign-up";
import Dashboard from "./pages/dashboard";
import ResetPass from "./pages/reset-pw";

function App() {
    const { Hub } = useContext(AmplifyContext);
    const {
        formType,
        setFormType,
        username,
        setUsername,
        error,
        setError,
        checkUser,
        handleLogOut,
    } = useContext(AuthContext);

    async function setAuthListener() {
        Hub.listen("auth", (data) => {
            switch (data.payload.event) {
                case "signIn":
                    console.log(`${username} signed in`);
                    break;
                case "signOut":
                    console.log("user signed out");
                    setFormType("login");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        checkUser();
        setAuthListener();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {formType === "signUp" && <SignUp />}
            {formType === "confirmSignUp" && <ConfirmSignUp />}
            {formType === "login" && <Login />}
            {formType === "dashboard" && (
                <Dashboard handleLogOut={handleLogOut} />
            )}
            {formType === "reset" && (
                <ResetPass />
            )}
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```